# How to work with local coordinates in libgdx custom group?

Tags: opengl, libgdx

I am creating a custom libgdx group to show a card image. It contains labels and images like these.

[image: Main image]

[image: Card Suit]

My first image is a texture region which is the actual size of the group. I now need to add the second image to the top left using local coordinate and a label for the name of the suit. This is the card I am using.

```
public class Card extends Group {

private Player player;

private AtlasRegion cardImage;

private Label lblCard;

public Card() {
    super();
    init();
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
    super.draw(batch, alpha);
    batch.draw(cardImage, getX(), getY());
    //lblName.draw()
    lblCard.draw(batch, getOriginX() + 70..values I have used for this arent working so far);
}

@Override
public void act(float delta){
}

@Override
public void setSize(float width, float height) {
    super.setSize(width, height);
}

private void init() {
        cardImage = Assets.instance.cards.hearts;

    // Add player name
    lblName = new Label("H", Assets.instance.menu, "knul-medium", Color.BLACK);
}
```

}

I have tried using `getX()` and `getY()` values but when I draw the group inside a table, only the `cardImage` fits onto the table whereas the labels all draw at one point in the screen. How can I draw the labels and other texture regions inside my Card using local coordinates and appear at same appear as one image whenever I create a new instance of Card in another class?

Comment: Change `getOriginX()` to `getX()`. The origin (distinct from position) is intended for things like center of rotation and is simply 0 if you haven't changed it.

Comment: Anyway, you are not really using Group as intended and you could have just subclassed Actor instead. Group manages children objects, whose positions are treated as relative to the group, so you would have just needed to add the card image and the label to the group at (0,0) and (70, y), respectively, and there would be no need to override `draw()`.